# Converting lambda or method group to Action<T> where T is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, types, lambda, type-conversion

I'm dynamically creating a type from a string passed to me at runtime.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
string messageType = "CustomerCreatedMessage";
//Convert the string to a Type
var type = Type.GetType(messageType);
//Create a Type of Action<CustomerCreatedMessage>
var action = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
```

How would I make a variable of the type of `action` and assign the lambda `m=> SetActive(true)` to it? I will then use the variable (named `???` here) in the following code:

```
//Create a generic method "Register" on my Messenger class that takes an Action<CustomerCreatedMessage> parameter.
var method = typeof(Messenger).GetMethod("Register");
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(action);
//Invoke the created method with our script in it
genericMethod.Invoke(Messenger.Default, ???);
```

My goal is to be able to call my generic method `Messenger.Default.Register<>` with an `Action<>` that takes as type parameter a type created from my `messageType` string.

I have tried the following already:

```
Convert.ChangeType(m=>SetActive(true),action);

var filledAction = Activator.CreateInstance(action);
filledAction = m=>SetActive(true);
```

But both methods complain about converting a lambda expression to an object because it is not a delegate.

I get a similar error if I put `SetActive(true)` into a method and try to pass the method group.

Comment: Just to check, do you really not care about the parameter?

Comment: Not at all, it's just to trigger the code when the message comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're not using the parameter at all, I'd create a new generic method:

```
private static void GenericSetActive<T>(T ignored)
{
    SetActive(true);
}
```

Then create a delegate using that:

```
var genericMethod = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("GenericSetActive",
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Static);
var concreteMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var actionInstance = Delegate.CreateDelegate(action, concreteMethod);
```

Basically, you can't use a lambda expression here because you don't have a specific delegate type to convert it to.

Comment: That certainly does it! I have one other question, does GenericSetActive have to be static? SetActive needs to run on the current instance, but when I change GenericSetActive to be non static Delegate.CreateDelegate complains: ArgumentException: method argument length mismatch despite the fact that I've not changed the parameters at all. I checked, and it is getting the GenericSetActive method correctly.

Comment: Scratch that, just noticed the overload Delegate.CreateDelegate(action, object, concreteMethod). Thanks a lot for you help!